# Azure Pipeline - Build one project from solution with project dependencies

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pipeline, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a solution that has a few projects.

- App.Client.Website
- App.Client.WindowsService
- App.Client.Database
- App.Client.Connectors
- App.Shared

The `App.Client.Database` and `App.Client.Connectors` are both dependencies of `App.Client.Website` and `App.Client.WindowsService`, and `App.Shared` is a dependency of all the projects.

I am wanting to create 2 pipelines: One for the website and one for the windows service.

The issue that I have is that when I set my *solution* to be `App.Client.Website/*.csproj`, it can't find any of my project references to build - which makes a lot of sense to me, but I would obviously like to have it build my project references as well.

I tried solving this by creating pipelines for each of the dependency projects that would pack a nuget package and then I would reference that nuget packages from the feed in my website and window service projects, but this stopped me from being able to debug the code and make changes in those project on the fly.

DevOps is something that I am only just starting to pick up. I have gotten to the point where I am needing to add build numbers to my website application and wanting to stop manually incrementing patch numbers. I am using YAML instead of the Classic pipeline builder.

Any and all help is appreciated.

**YAML**
Here is the YAML that I am using. It is just the basic YAML with the solution targeting my Website project.

```
# ASP.NET
# Build and test ASP.NET projects.
# Add steps that publish symbols, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/aspnet/build-aspnet-4

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.Client.Website/*.csproj'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
    feedsToUse: 'config'
    nugetConfigPath: 'Pipelines/nuget.config'
    externalFeedCredentials: 'External Feed'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

The repo folder structure has the project folders at the root of repo.

My project references in my Website cs project file are as follows:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\App.Client.Database\App.Client.Database.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\App.Client.Connectors\App.Client.Connectors.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\App.Shared\App.Shared.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Here is an error from the build task:

`##[error]C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.403\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(241,5): Error NETSDK1004: Assets file 'D:\a\1\s\App.Shared\obj\project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file.`

Comment: Can you add your YAML pipeline?

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej Updated my question. It is mostly just the default template provided.

Comment: Since oy have to build almost all projects why not use `**/*.sln`?

Comment: Hi @JohZant, could you share the repo directory structure, then open the file such as App.Client.Website.csproj search ProjectReference, then share the Project Reference path here? If the path is incorrect, we will see the warning message : The referenced project '..\App.Client.Connectors\App.Client.Connectors1.csproj' does not exist.

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej I am using a task to version the website. I don't want that same version on the window service

Comment: @VitoLiu-MSFT Question is updated. All project folders are in the root folder.

Comment: Of course, i am not saying to have one pipeline. But to build whole solution in each one.

Comment: Hi @JohZant, This issue is related to the NuGet restore task, could you try to restore the .sln file and then kindly share the result here?

Comment: @VitoLiu-MSFT Having the entire solution as the solution in the Nuget Restore command and only building the required project worked! It didn't even cross my mind that I could do that. As I have said, I am very new to Dev Ops, and I work in a small shop where we don't have the resources for a fulltime devops person. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is related to the `NuGet Restore` task, We could try to restore the `.sln` file to restore all NuGet packages, and then build the `.csproj` file. It should work.